# Print Objects to file txt

Tags: java

I'm trying to print objects into file.
Then I want to import them back to my program.
ObjectOutputStream not working, What am I missing? (try, catch not visible here but they're doing their job)

```
Map< Account, Customer> customerInfo = new HashMap< Account, Customer>();

File bankFile = new File("Bank.txt");
                FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream( bankFile);
                ObjectOutputStream objOut = new ObjectOutputStream(fOut);

                for(Map.Entry<Account, Customer> e : bank.customerInfo.entrySet())
                    {
                        objOut.writeObject(e.getValue());
                        objOut.writeObject(e.getKey());
                    }

                objOut.flush();
                objOut.close();
                fOut.close();
```

My problem here is that ObjectOutputStream is not working properly, it prints some weird code. I've used other methods to print out to file and they work just fine.

I've tried printing to different file extensions,

I tried changing the encoding for both the file and eclipse.

I tried different methods for getting the info from the Map using ObjectOutputStream. Is there a reason why ObjectOutputStream prints weird characters that I haven't think of? The entire file is almost impossible to read. Thanks!

Ps. some of the weird print, don't know if it helps.

¬ísrCustomerDìUðkJ
personalIdNumLnametLjava/lang/String;xpthellosr
SavingAccountUÞÀÀÍ¾>ZfreeWithdrawDwithdrawalInterestRateLaccountTypeq~xrAccount é=UáÐI
accountNumberDbalanceDinterestRateLaccountTypeq~L   transListtLjava/util/List;xpé?záG®{tsrjava.util.ArrayListxÒÇaIsizexpw
x?záG®{tSaving Accountq~sr
CreditAccountÝ
*5&­VcLaccountTypeq~xq~ê?záG®{q~sq~ w
xtCredit Account

Comment: You should stick to Serializable. What trouble have you had with it?

Comment: I'd go with serialization or if you want to save the information in a text-readable format then use JAXB.

Comment: Go for serialization. and implement toString method.

Comment: Yes, I guess I have to read more about Serializable until I get it into my head. I'm curious about JAXB, new word to my vocabulary. Implementing the string in my bank manager sounds good. Didn't have a toString in this class since I was using the toString from each class to display the info.

Comment: Actually the best answer for a problem like this is to use a formal relational database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really quite simple. First things first, create a class that implements `Serializable`. `Serializable` is a marker interface, so you don't need to implement any methods for it:

```
public class Shoe implements Serializable  { ... }
```

---

***NOTE***: If `Shoe` has other classes in it, for example `Heel`, or `Buckle`, those classes also need to implement the `Serializable` interface.

---

Next step is to write that to a file, using an `ObjectOutputStream`.

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("myfile.txt");
// Create the stream to the file you want to write too.
ObjectOutputStream objOut = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
// Use the FileOutputStream as the constructor argument for your object.

objOut.writeObject(new Shoe("Prada"));
// Write your object to the output stream.
objOut.close();
// MAKE SURE YOU CLOSE to avoid memory leaks, and make sure it actually writes.
```

There you have it. The serialized object is written to the txt file. Now to read it, it's just a case of using the `ObjectInputStream`.

```
ObjectInputStream objIn = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("myfile.txt");
Object obj = objIn.readObject();
if(obj instanceof Shoe)
{
    Shoe shoe = (Shoe)obj;
}
```

And you've got an object you can use.

Comment: I got it but my case is not only about a shoe is about a customer who has different accounts and different transactions. And my class Bank logic is the one that makes/create the object.

Comment: What's the difference? If you want to go the Serializable way, just make Customer, Account and Transaction Serializable and read and write them as needed.

Comment: I'm not going to write it for you, because then you won't learn anything. Try to understand the *concepts* in my answer, and then apply them to your specific problem.

Comment: Hey thank you Chris, I'm applying your concept see how it goes. Didn't know you can/has to serialize all the classes involved. So thanks for the tip Costis.

Comment: Apologies, I should have mentioned. I've added it into my answer :)

Comment: This is not exactly working for me. Although I'm doing some implementation to my classes in order to print the avoid mentioned.I'll be giving an extended answer to this questions once I'm done.

Comment: What's wrong with it? How is it behaving? Please be more specific so I can edit my answer.

Comment: Chris! Thank you for your support! I think your answer is right! it was my code that was missing some implementation but now I'm having another problem with the same ObjectOutputStream. I've updated my question, see above.